# Google Tag Manager gtm.click {{Click Text}}

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have a table list with details from shops, such as opening hours, phone numbers etc. When a user clicks the shops name, the before mentioned details appear using javascript.

I would like to retrieve the shops name (SHOP NAME) whenever a user clicks it using Tag Manager and then show the information in Google Analytics. I've tried several things in GTM without any luck.

Any help is really appreciated.

The code is as follows:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="row" valign="top">
        <td class="locationGridColZip" onclick="javascript: locationGridAddressToggle(this);">
          <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$ContentRegion$ctl00$locationGridView$ctl02$hfStore" id="ctl00_ContentRegion_ctl00_locationGridView_ctl02_hfStore" value="2620|55,65739|12,35353">CITY
            </td>
            <td class="locationGridColImgOFF" onclick="javascript: locationGridAddressToggle(this);">
            </td>
            <td class="locationGridColAddress" onclick="javascript: locationGridAddressToggle(this);">
              <h3>SHOP NAME</h3>                    
            </td>
            <td class="locationGridColShow">
              <a onclick="javascript:map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(55.65739, 12.35353));map.setZoom(12);" href="/butikker.aspx#gmap">SHOW ON MAP</a>
              <a class="countryGmap countryGmap1" onclick="javascript:map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(55.65739, 12.35353));map.setZoom(12);" href="/butikker.aspx#gmap"><img src="https://cdn.fotoagent.dk/webshop/production_solr/images/gmapDanmarkAlt.gif" alt="Vis på kort" style="border-width:0px;"></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Are you able to post the link to the page in question?

Comment: Go in debug mode and click on the element of your choice. Now in the GTM debug console there should be the click in your list. Select the click and look up the values of your variables. The Click Element variables contain the values you probably are looking for.

Comment: @nyuen The page in question is https://www.skoringen.dk/butikker.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Since you have jQuery enabled, you could enable it in a Custom JS variable with the following (please modify as needed):

```
function(){
   try{
      var ce = {{Click Element}};
      var storeName = $(ce).closest('tr').find('.locationGridColZip').text().trim();
      if (storeName.length > 0){
         return storeName;
      }
      return 'undefined';
   }
   catch(e){
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a custom JavaScript variable. It will depend on your circumstances, in particular which element the 'click element' identifies at the point you'd like the tag to fire, but I would use something akin to:

```
function ()
{
  return {{Click Element}}.getElementsByTagName("h3")
}
```

There are some good example of custom Javascript variables here:
http://www.apasters.com/blog/google-tag-manager-custom-javascript-variable-examples/

There's also a good general overview by Simo Ahava here:
http://www.simoahava.com/analytics/variable-guide-google-tag-manager/#6